# HTTP DELETE function behaving radically with JSON-server

Tags: angular, http, observable, angular-httpclient, json-server

I am trying to send HTTP requests to a JSON-server in my Angular app, to update a JSON file.

When I try to delete one `job` object, multiple jobs are being deleted rather than the one I specified.

Here is my `Job Service` code delete method:

```
baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/jobs';

deleteJob(id: number): Observable<void> {
    return this.httpClient.delete<void>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

And here is some of my JSON file:

```
"jobs": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "UI UX",
      "description": "DESC",
      "employeeId": "2",
      "managerId": "1",
      "imageUrl": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "devops",
      "description": "asdf",
      "employeeId": "1",
      "managerId": "13",
      "imageUrl": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "asdf",
      "description": "adf",
      "employeeId": "",
      "managerId": "1",
      "imageUrl": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "title": "asdf",
      "description": "adf",
      "employeeId": "",
      "managerId": "1",
      "imageUrl": ""
    }
  ],
```

If I pass 6 as the ID to the `deleteJob()` method. Instead of deleting just that job object, jobs with ID's 2,3 & 6 are deleted, and this is printed in console:

> DELETE /jobs/6

I thought the problem might be to do with `baseUrl`, because it doesn't specify the `id` attribute.

So I tried this:

```
deleteUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/jobs/id';

deleteJob(id: number): Observable<void> {
    return this.httpClient.delete<void>(`${this.deleteUrl}/${id}`)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

But now, no `jobs` are being deleted, & I get this message in the console:

> DELETE /jobs/id/6 404 (Not Found)

Can someone please tell me why this behaviour is happening & how I can resolve it?

Comment: The first service call is the correct one from a REST point of view.

Comment: Hi @David As in I should use `baseUrl`?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to have `id` in the url, `/jobs/6` should normally work. I've never used json server, but by looking at the docs what you have should be working...